# Getting started with writing a desktop app that talks to an iPhone

Tags: c#, iphone

I'm thinking of writing an app to selectively transfer photos/music to and from my iPhone, mostly for fun and personal convenience. However, I'm stuck at the very beginning -- where do I look to find information on how to do this?

Pretty much every link I see talks about developing applications that run on the iPhone, but nothing about desktop app for interfacing with an iPhone.

I'm on Windows (no access to a Mac, but I'll take suggestions for that for when I eventually acquire one), and I'm most familiar with C#, but other languages are definitely an option.

Can anybody offer me a few pointers on getting started? Thanks.

Edit: to clarify further, I don't need information on how to write applications that run ON the iphone. There are plenty of resources out for that. :) What I'm looking for it some pointers on how to "talk" to an iPhone or an iPod through the USB cord, if that's even possible.

Edit #2: I found [libmobiledevice](http://libimobiledevice.org/) library that effectively does what I'm talking about on Linux. I don't think I'm too keen on attempting to port it over to Windows, though. :)

Comment: Maybe you can try transfering the files using sockets I dont know if you can program sockets on iPhone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found what I was looking for: [SharePodLib](http://www.getsharepod.com/fordevelopers/). Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend and have used the following options:

**Option 1:**

Run a small and light webserver in the iPhone and of course, use HTTP to transfer. I recommend [mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) websever, i've tried it with very simple and very heavy load. Also [here](http://github.com/face/MongooseDaemon), you can find an actual drag and drop project to deploy this webserver in the iPhone.

**Option 2:**

Use something like Bonjour, this is something very useful if you want the "smart" discovery of your device in the network, maybe for opportunistic peer discovery. You can check [here](http://www.tuaw.com/2007/10/22/mdns-and-caffeine-how-i-got-bonjour-running-on-my-iphone/) and [here](http://www.mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/), to understand how to get bonjour to run in the iPhone and use it to exploit discovery and sharing.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this isn't what I'm looking for at all. I can't write applications that run ON the iPhone.

I'm also not talking about network discovery. I'm looking for info on how to work with an iPhone connected to the PC with the good ol' USB cord. What commands I can send across that wire to get, say, a list of music available on the phone and how to go about doing so, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no no way to sync an iPhone app with a Mac app over USB, at least in the current SDK.  As already stated, you'll have to either sync over HTTP or use the local network.  You might want to check out [ZSync](http://github.com/mzarra/ZSync), a Cocoa library for bonjour syncing (I haven't used it, and it's in early development stages, but it looks interesting).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no officially sanctioned method to do what you describe.  In Apple's view the only application that should have visibility of that information is iTunes.  There are applications out there that appear to be able to do this, but I suspect they have reverse engineered the USB protocol and are thus open to being locked out if the protocol changes.