# How to access iphone hdd from ios app and windows app (through USB)?

Tags: iphone, ios, usb, jailbreak

I need to be able to save data from windows application to hdd of iphone through usb. Then I need to read it from application running on iphone.

What i tried:
I did install "USB drive" on iphone and created disk. Now I'm able to save data from windows on iphone, but I don't know how to access this drive in ios app. Anybody have any ideas? Device is jailbroken so every "non official" solution is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting started with writing a desktop app that talks to an iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489985/getting-started-with-writing-a-desktop-app-that-talks-to-an-iphone)

Comment: See also [How do I programmatically access the filesystem of an iOS device connected to a Windows desktop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783072/how-do-i-programmatically-access-the-filesystem-of-an-ios-device-connected-to-a-w)

Answer (score 1):

Every Application runs in a Sandbox. So you can't get in and can't get out.

Non Jailbroken solution:
Add UIFileSharingEnable to info.plist and set it to YES

Now you can copy files from your windows machine to your iOS Device via iTunes

Filepath of your Files:

```
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *sDocumentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:sDocumentsDir];
filePath = [[filePath stringByAppendingString:@"/"] stringByAppendingString:@"file.txt"];
```

Comment: thanks, but how can I upload files to iphone using my own windows app?

Comment: This is only possible with jailbroken devices and I'm not familiar with that. Sorry.